# Python OpenCV How to draw ractangle center of image and crop image inside rectangle?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I use Python3 OpenCV3. I want to draw ractangle center of image and crop image inside rectangle.
I try to run this code but rectangle not show at the center of image.

```
width, height, channels = img.shape
cv2.rectangle(img,(0,0),(int(width/2), int(height/2)), (0,255,0) , 2)
```

How to draw ractangle center of image and crop image inside rectangle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## create an image

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(100, 150, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
```

[image: img]

## draw a rectangle

```py
height, width, channels = img.shape
upper_left = (width // 4, height // 4)
bottom_right = (width * 3 // 4, height * 3 // 4)
# draw in the image
cv2.rectangle(img, upper_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.imshow('draw_img', img)
```

[image]

## fill values by indexing

```py
# indexing array
rect_img = img[upper_left[1]: bottom_right[1] + 1, upper_left[0]: bottom_right[0] + 1]
rect_img[:] = (255, 0, 0)  # modify value
cv2.imshow('index_img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`numpy slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) in order to crop the image.

The way `OpenCV` stores an image is as a `numpy array`. This means that you can 'crop' them as you can a `numpy` array.

The way to do this is with the following `syntax`:

```
cropped = img[top_edge : bottom_edge, left_edge : right_edge]
```

*where `top_edge`, `bottom_edge` etc. are `pixels` vals*.

The reason this works is because `numpy` `slicing` allows you to `slice` along any `axis` - each one separated by a comma.

So here, we are `slicing` the `rows` of the image to between `top_edge` and `bottom_edge` and then the comma says that what comes next is going to effect the `columns` in each `row`. So for a given `row`, we `slice` it between `left_edge` and `right_edge`. And that's it!

Hope this is useful! **:)**